# Woocommerce Standard Tax Table Missing in Admin

Tags: woocommerce

I am wrapping up a new website, and I am having a major issue with the standard tax rates not being visible in the admin panel.  The rates are being calculated on the front end, and the data is in SQL, but the entire administrative side of things is invisible.
See attached image
[image]

While the site was still on the external testing server, the client's accounting department went in and uploaded all applicable tax rates using the sample spreadsheet and the Tax Rate Upload plugin.  Everything was fine.  I eventually migrated the site to its permanent home (using All-in-One WP Migration), and the administrative functionality of the tax rates is gone.

If I dump the tax tables in SQL, it restores the functionality.  I've dumped them through phpMyAdmin as well as through the System Status > Tools feature multiple times, each time importing the tax data again from an CSV downloaded from the original testing site.  Nothing.

Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks!